# Google App Script converting formulas of Excel files to #Ref

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import Excel files from Gmail and convert them automatically to a Google Spreadsheet. I've stumbled upon a problem when using Google Api file converter, that formulas are converted to #REF value and I can't get the original value that shows in the Excel file.

[Orinial Excel File data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R40LX.jpg)

**Example of formulas an external party uses in the Excel files for that data**

> =VLOOKUP(A4;'G:\Some local path\file.xlsx'!$A:$D;4;FALSE)

I'm using the following code to convert the Excel file to a Google Spreadsheet:

```
  // Re-upload the XLS file after convert in Google Sheet format
  var googleSheet = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&convert=true", {
      method: "POST",
      contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
      payload: sourceFile.getBlob().getBytes(),
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    }
  );

  // Parse upload&convert response data (need this to be able to get id of converted sheet)
  var fileDataResponse = JSON.parse(googleSheet.getContentText());
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileDataResponse.id);
```

When opening the created/converted spreadsheet, all values in the cells show as #REF! (see below).

[Output values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBYoE.jpg)

How can I make sure Google API converts/copies the source as values and does not show the formula #REF! error?

Comment: Well how exactly do you expect that formula - which contains an invalid and unknown reference to Google - to be evaluated? I suspect if you were to open that Excel sheet from a computer without access to that G drive, using Excel, it would flag the formula as `#REF`. The solution is to get rid of that formula in the actual file before you upload it for conversion.

Comment: When I open the file in Excel it will show the 'initial' value as calculated by the sender. So this data must somehow be stored into the Exel file.

Comment: sounds like you need to write an export macro to run from/on client sheets before they get uploaded. You'll still need check for ref in the documents you get though, because it will get exploited or the pre export steps will be forgotten at some point

Answer (score 1):

Not all the Excel and Google Sheets are the same on each other. The Google Drive / Google Sheet built-in import feature already has a way to handle non supported functions but as your code is using UrlFetchApp to  upload the file your script should include it's own way to handle the unsupported formulas / features.

Related Q&A

- [Are Excel formulas and Google Spreadsheet formulas the same?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/15458/88163)